# ¿Cómo puedo hacer varias peticiones requests a una misma web?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Tengo que realizar 100 llamadas a la web 'http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/' porque me dará 100 tipos de actividades diferentes. Pero no consigo sacar el código, entiendo que debería de hacer el requests.get de la url i a parte recorrerlo 100 veces pero no me sale. El API es de tipo JSON, por eso genero un diccionario. Os dejo la parte de código que he podido hacer:

```
import json

url = 'http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/'
response = requests.get(url)
act_dict = json.loads(response.text)

for item in act_dict.items():
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Una solución que requiere mínima modificación al código original.*

El código original recupera una actividad (como diccionario). La modificación consiste en ejecutarlo repetidas veces, agregando cada nuevo diccionario a una lista de actividades. Cuando esta lista complete 100 elementos, paramos.

Traducido a código: tengo que encerrar el código en un `while` mientras `len(actividades)` sea menor a 100:

```
url = 'http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/'
actividades = []
while len(actividades) < 100:
    response = requests.get(url)
    act_dict = json.loads(response.text)
    actividades.append(act_dict)
```

El resultado del código es que `actividades` es una lista con 100 diccionarios, cada uno con la info de una actividad en particular.

#### Demo

Reunir 100 actividades tarda, asi que hare la demo con 5:

```
import json
import requests

url = 'http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/'
actividades = []
while len(actividades) < 5:
    response = requests.get(url)
    act_dict = json.loads(response.text)
    actividades.append(act_dict)

for item in actividades:
    print(item)
```

produce:

```
{'activity': 'Organize a bookshelf', 'type': 'busywork', 'participants': 1, 'price': 0, 'link': '', 'key': '6098037', 'accessibility': 0}
{'activity': 'Go to a karaoke bar with some friends', 'type': 'social', 'participants': 4, 'price': 0.5, 'link': '', 'key': '9072906', 'accessibility': 0.35}
{'activity': 'Make a new friend', 'type': 'social', 'participants': 1, 'price': 0, 'link': '', 'key': '1000000', 'accessibility': 0}
{'activity': 'Pick up litter around your favorite park', 'type': 'charity', 'participants': 1, 'price': 0, 'link': '', 'key': '4894697', 'accessibility': 0.05}
{'activity': 'Compliment someone', 'type': 'social', 'participants': 2, 'price': 0, 'link': '', 'key': '9149470', 'accessibility': 0}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias.